# Keys cannot be read to use boto with s3 - Windows Anaconda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, anaconda

I'm using python 3.7 on Windows with Anaconda. I'm trying to follow the instructions on Boto Quickstart but it fails to locate the credentials.

I'm following the instructions here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#using-boto-3

I have stored the two files with key location here:

`C:\Users\MyUser\\.aws\`

When I execute:

```py
for bucket in s3.buckets.all(): 
    print(bucket.name)
```

the error message is:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError

NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Comment: If the credentials and config files are in %USERPROFILE%\.aws\, and they are correctly formatted, and you have a default profile, then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to the config you've setup `C:\Users\MyUser\.aws\config`?

If it is, the likely reason for the error is a pathing issue where Anaconda's version of python (which lives in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\`) is unable to find your AWS credentials as Anaconda python won't be looking in `C:\Users\MyUser\` (or consequently, `C:\Users\MyUser\.aws\`) by default.

---

As for how to fix this, you have [multiple options for providing authentication to a boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html). To choose the closest option to the method you've chosen (directly pulling from a `config` file),

- First, open an anaconda prompt and type: `echo %PATH%`

This is the root path for the Anaconda python interpreter. We'll need this to figure out what directory Anaconda python looks for by default.

- Move (or copy) your `.aws/` folder (with the `config` file inside of it) into this location.

Now, `boto3` being run from Anaconda python should automatically be able to find these credentials.

Comment: Hi nmwalsh, thank you. i receive a long list of folders by using echo %PATH%.